# MySQL server experiencing high stress/max connections

Tags: mysql, php, pdo

**The Short:**
We're hitting max connections and seeing very poor performance from MySQL during peak business hours and cannot determine if it is a load problem or a configuration problem.

**The Long:**
To begin, here’s our server specs hosted on Digital Ocean:

Cores: 20

*Memory:*

total            used    free          shared      buff/cache       available
Mem:            62G         48G        4.7G        216M         10G         14G

*MySQL WorkBench Dashboard Snapshot:*

[MySQL Workbench Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHBEZ.png)

We typically have over 200 entries in processlist, almost all of which are "Opening tables", "closing tables", and, slightly less frequent, "cleaning up".  The cleaning up entries have COMMAND `killed` and `NULL` INFO (`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST`). 
The only queries we really see taking very long are some INSERTS into tables with heavy use, and UPDATE commands with the primary key in the WHERE for tables with heavy us.  Their state is “update” in the processlist.

*MySQL .cnf settings:*

```
key_buffer_size=1G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=1073741824
max_length_for_sort_data=8388608
max_sort_length=8388608
sort_buffer_size=1073741824
join_buffer_size=1073741824
preload_buffer_size=1073741824
read_buffer_size=1073741824
read_rnd_buffer_size=1073741824
thread_cache_size=450
max_allowed_packet=100M
max_connections=400
lock_wait_timeout=50
wait_timeout=120
table_open_cache_instances=10
table_open_cache=6000
table_definition_cache=6000
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size=46G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=46
```

We have 800+ databases on our single live server, and many thousands of users using an app that makes frequent server requests with lots of individual record updates or inserts that need to sync to multiple users.

**The Question:**

Given the .cnf settings and our server specs, in relation to the MySQL WorkBench dashboard snapshot, should we be experiencing the kind of slowdown/connections we're seeing with this configuration? 
We constantly hit our Max Connections and get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Resource temporarily unavailable` errors in PHP from PDO.

Does anyone have any suggestions to improve the performance? Different config settings? We know long term solutions, like putting large clients on separate servers, among others—but for the short term, is there any way to optimize our server? Our app and website are barely usable during the rush hours.

Additional Stat:

Linux 4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64
    04/25/2016  _x86_64_    (20 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle

8.51    0.01    0.67    0.28    0.35   90.18

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
vda
269.78      1681.90      2180.52 37679232421 48849706700

Comment: What about another system metrics? What is CPU load and utilization? If there is lot of IO WAIT, your disk subsystem is bottle neck.

Comment: See the updated io stat at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on "configuration" – but probably in the opposite way you anticipate... I suspect you've configured it too much.

It looks to me as if you've been "tuning" your server's performance [right into the ground](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45570/11651).

If you have been using a "tuning" script – stop doing that.

For example... `table_definition_cache=6000` and `table_open_cache=6000` ... what is the justification for this?

Most of the parameters you have configured away from their defaults seem like guesswork.

Unless you benchmarked *each* of these customizations, individually, before and after you made them, individually... well, you probably see where I'm going... they're probably unjustified, and you are likely to be better off without them.  Bigger isn't always better.  Bigger can be harder to juggle.

I would expect good things if you'd simply comment out *almost all* of these settings except for `innodb_*` and let the server run with more parameters at their default values.